# how to install et-3750 ubuntu 17.1

Tags: printing, epson

I dl the epson drivers, got epson recommendation to apt-get install lsb. I think I need more stuff in term before this part works, so,
what do I need to type in to get apt-get to work,
what's next...?
thanks! st

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: Please provide more detail including the command you typed, and what response you get (also edit and add it to your question, questions/answers allow more editing/formatting).  For example you mention apt-get needing more stuff; apt-get requires elevated permissions so use `sudo apt-get install ...` but best if you just follow the instructions you were provided (if you need help with them, best to provide the link for us to read too)

Comment: so Epson updated the driver on 26th Feb 2018; for 64bit ubuntu, you need  epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2_1.0.12-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb from here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=70277&DSCCHK=cf9fcfbdddcccd56ca87c74aec096f52e14c7888 and it is a debian file so should install easily thus installing the printer driver and registering the printer with lpadmin

Answer (score 1):

While Ubuntu 18.04 recognizes this printer out of the box, setting up the scanner need a few more steps. Precondition is, that scanner and Ubuntu client are in the same network. And you will have to find out the IP address from your scanner/printer.

1. Search on Epson website for your driver: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX
2. Download `imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-18.04-1.3.40.x64.deb.tar.gz` from here: http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php?version=1.3.40
3. Extract archive and change into directory. Call install script via `sudo ./install.sh` That installs several packages for you. One is `imagescan`, a replacement for simple scan - but you won't need it in the end.
4. Do a `cat /etc/sane.d/dll.con` and check that there is no comment sign before `epson`, `epson2` or `epkowa`. It may be the last one is missing, nevermind. If there is a comment sign before one of those entries, open the files as root and remove it (`sudo gedit /path/o/file`).
5. Use `sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` OR (if there is no epkowa) `sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epson2` as root and insert the following line:
   `net 192.168.1.111 1865`. You have to replace `192.168.1.111` with the IP address of your printer/scanner. Save and close file.
6. Now open `imagescan` configuration file with `sudo gedit /etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf` and insert the following code:

   ```
   [devices]

   net.udi = networkscan:esci://192.168.1.111:1865
   net.vendor = Epson
   net.model = ET-3750
   net.name = Epson ET-3750
   ```
7. Again: Replace `192.168.1.111` with the IP address of your scanner/printer and the other Informations with the type of your Scanner/printer if it differs from `ET-3750`. Save and close. If you start `simple-scan` now, your scanner should be available.

Comment: As of at least Epson's imagescan v3.55 the `sane` driver is called `imagescan` and gets configured by the deb package itself by inserting a file `/etc/sane.d/dll.d/imagescan`. That's the used to access the scanning device over USB.

Comment: `/etc/sane.d/epson2.conf` contains `net autodiscovery` on my Ubuntu 19.10. But I needed the entry in `/etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf ` to have my network ET-3750 detected by `simple-scan`. Thank you!